# removing themes from drupal

Tags: drupal, themes

How do I remove a theme from drupal?

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK just delete its folder from `/sites/all/themes`

Comment: the directory is in themes.  I renamed it and it still appears

Comment: There's no reason to remove core themes. Just disable them.

Comment: renaming the directory will not work, deleting it will. Theme discovery is not based on the directory structure/naming within ./themes/ but the info in the .info files

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure the theme is disabled.
2. Delete the corresponding theme directory, likely in "/sites/all/themes", **after** having disabled it.
   Reference: [Uninstalling Themes / Deleting Themes | Drupal.org](http://www.drupal.org/node/1040166)

Comment: how can I delete it through the GUI ?

Answer (score 0):

um the GUI way is accessing https://yoursite/admin/appearance/uninstall
it is the last tab that appears along with the Appearance header, when you have clicked on Appearance (depending on the theme that you use this might be different)

[image: appearance_tabs]